# Google Map is not showing in Android Studio (Only Google Icon is Visible)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to import Google Map SDK in my project. According to Docs I follow all the steps perfectly but when i run the project it only show an icon of google instead of Google Map.

I search a lot but nothing find to solve my problem

Here is my Main Activity named as GoogleMapLocat:

```
public class GoogleMapLocat extends AppCompatActivity {
//map data
private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map_locat);

    //map data
    if (isServicesOK()) {
        init();
    }
}
//MAP DATA
public void init() {
    Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
    btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapLocat.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public boolean isServicesOK() {
    Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");
    int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GoogleMapLocat.this);
    if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Services is Working");
        return true;
    } else if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)) {
        //an error occured but we can resolve it
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
        Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(GoogleMapLocat.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you can,t make map request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is my Second Activity named as MapActivity:

```
 public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

 private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
 private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

//vars
private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    getLocationPermission();
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;
}

private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                //initialize our map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

GoogleMapLocat.xml is here:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GoogleMapLocat">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Map"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

MapActivity.xml is here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

What,s wrong in this code?It only shows google icon  in left corner at the bottom of screen instead of map.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few days ago.

Try to remove "Application restrictions" on Google API Console.

It worked for me.

Comment: You saved me but will this method not secure?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you have configured the google map key. You have to define it in the manifest. You can define with this line:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE" />
```

You can review this link to get your key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

Comment: I also  configured the api key but it doesn,t show map,,,please guide

Comment: Be sure that permissions are added in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Check that SHA-1 certificate fingerprint was correctly added to console and enable Maps SDK for Android https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk. By the way, share your api key is not secure, please edit to remove from comment.

Comment: SHA-1 certificate fingerprint is also added to console and Maps Sdk is already enabled

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you must define 2 APIs for release & debug in APIs & credentials.

For example, use debug & release sign key in both APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing on device and it was not connected to internet...
I connected to WiFi and map started showing, if was silently failing.

If someone end up on this question, don't forget to check your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too and I had ensured that:

1. The project SDK was setup correctly
2. Google Console was setup correctly with no key restriction

I confirmed the above by using the same key in other android project and the map could load successfully. Then I created another new android project with the same package name with my original one and surprising this time the map could not load again. I concluded it was the package name that made the map loading failed. I am not sure why but I solved this by refactoring my package name to another one.